# Can't get zbu.ModelsBuilder to work in Umbraco 7

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I am using Umbraco 7, and have just installed the zbu Models Builder Integration package for asp.net using nuget (by running `Install-Package Zbu.ModelsBuilder.AspNet -Pre` in my NuGet Package Manager console) (which, from what I can see, always installs both zbu.ModelsBuilder and zbu.ModelsBuilder.AspNet dlls).

But I could not have a taste of this thing working yet.

In my Developer section under the new tab "Models Builder", it seems the page that is being displayed there is incomplete (if I look at the file BuildModels.ascx, which seems to be what is supposed to be rendered there - the asp:PlaceHolder whose ID is 'phGenerate' is not rendering/is missing - I do not see however any errors in chrome's console). Seems to me that I need to press this "Generate" (declared within the placeholder) button to trigger the process.

I tried generating the models using the extension for Visual Studio as well, but to no avail again. Right clicking the newly created cs file and choosing "Run Custom Tool" shows the error "The custom tool 'Zbu.ModelsBuilder' failed. One or more errors occurred.".

I found 2 existing threads in Umbraco Forums on issues on Zbu.ModelsBuilder, but **they do not help me**:

1. https://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/hybrid-framework-for-umbraco-v7/anything/59445-Issues-with-zbuModelsBuilder
2. https://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/hybrid-framework-for-umbraco-v7/anything/58147-Zbu-ModelsBuilder-API-version-conflict

Comment: I don't think stephan (the author) is monitoring stackoverflow.  So if you post on our.umbraco.org, he'll catch up.  Certainly if you ping him on twitter (zpqrtbnk).

Comment: I wondered if anyone else could help. Yup, I primarily posted this in our.umbraco.org, and also traced him on twitter today asking him to give a  look.